# How do I lock specific cells within a row based on drop down selection in excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, validation, vba

I have set conditional formatting so specific options have a unique colour, I would now like to create a macro so the cell/s corresponding based on the colour are editable and all other cells in the row for that drop down are read only.

So for example A5 is selected as "Toyota" meaning only E5 in row five would be editable as the formatting in A5 matches E2.

Screenshot of cells:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Change` event to modify the `Locked` property of cells, something like this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rw As Range, rHdr As Range, cl As Range

    Me.Unprotect
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        Set rHdr = Me.UsedRange.Rows(1)

        For Each rw In Target.Rows
            If rw.Cells(1, 1) <> "" Then
                For Each cl In rHdr.Cells
                    Me.Cells(rw.Row, cl.Column).Locked = Not (cl.Value Like rw.Cells(1, 1) & "*")
                Next
            Else
                rw.Locked = True
            End If
            rw.Cells(1, 1).Locked = False
        Next
    End If
    Me.Protect
End Sub
```

Comment: UsedRange starts from the first used row, not A1, so in this particular case `UsedRange.Rows(2)` will be Row 3...